# Missing pictures in folder

Tags: windows-xp

I had a folder with some pictures, somehow these pictures are "missing" and I cannot see them anymore.

The strange thing is that if I use the "preview" view in Explorer (the one that shows the tiny icons of the folder contents), the folder preview shows these pictures as if they were inside. Once I enter the folder, they are not there anymore.

I tried showing hidden files and folders, that doesn't help.

Any ideas on how to show or recover those files?

Answer (score 0):

If you can not see them, I would say make sure you also have disabled the hide system files option on the unlikely event that they were marked that way.

I would first try pressing <kbd>F5</kbd> just in case they are there, but not being updated.

The only other thing I can think of is that they are somehow cached. The thumbnails do not get updated in real time, and it is possible your thumbs.db file in that folder is displaying old content.

I hope this helps, but I fear it won't.